# I have three loops over an array of (char*) elements in C. Why does the third fail?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

While experimenting with methods for stepping through an array of strings in C, I developed the following small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef char* string;

int main() {
  char *family1[4] = {"father", "mother", "son", NULL};
  string family2[4] = {"father", "mother", "son", NULL};

  /* Loop #1: Using a simple pointer to step through "family1". */
  for (char **p = family1; *p != NULL; p++) {
    printf("%s\n", *p);
  }
  putchar('\n');

  /* Loop #2: Using the typedef for clarity and stepping through
   * family2. */
  for (string *s = family2; *s != NULL; s++) {
    printf("%s\n", *s);
  }
  putchar('\n');

  /* Loop #3: Again, we use the pointer, but with a unique increment
   * step in our for loop.  This fails to work.  Why? */
  for (string s = family2[0]; s != NULL; s = *(&s + 1)) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
  }
}
```

My specific question involves the failure of Loop #3.  When run through the debugger, Loops #1 and #2 complete successfully, but the last loop fails for an unknown reason.  I would not have asked this here, except for the fact that is shows me that I have some critical misunderstanding regarding the "&" operator.

**My question (and current understanding) is this:**
  `family2` is an array-of-pointer-to-char. Thus, when `s` is set to `family2[0]` we have a `(char*)` pointing to "father".  Therefore, taking `&s` should give us the equivalent of `family2`, pointing to the first element of `family2` after the expected pointer decay.  Why doesn't, then,
`*(&s + 1)` point to the next element, as expected?

Many thanks,
lifecrisis

---

**EDIT -- Update and Lessons Learned:**

The following list is a summary of all of the relevant facts and interpretations that explain why the third loop does not work like the first two.

1. `s` is a separate variable holding a copy of the value (a pointer-to-char) from the variable `family2[0]`. I.e., these two equivalent values are positioned at SEPARATE locations in memory.
2. `family2[0]` up to `family2[3]` are contiguous elements of memory, and `s` has no presence in this space, though it does contain the same value that is stored in `family2[0]` at the start of our loop.
3. These first two facts mean that `&s` and `&family2[0]` are NOT equal. Thus, adding one to `&s` will return a pointer to unknown/undefined data, whereas adding one to `&family2[0]` will give you `&family2[1]`, as desired.
4. In addition, the update step in the third for loop doesn't actually result in s stepping forward in memory on each iteration. This is because `&s` is constant throughout all iterations of our loop. This is the cause of the observed infinite loop.

Thanks to EVERYONE for their help!
lifecrisis

Comment: What is `string`? C does not have a string type.

Comment: Notice the typedef at the top of the code block! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, yes! So the other warning applies: **Never ever** `typedef` a pointer! It obfuscates the code, spams the namespace and makes qualifier-correct code difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Never a good idea to `typedef` pointers. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems that you're satisfied with the answers.  If so, you should [accept one of them](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @dbush Good suggestion.  I'm obviously new to Stack Overflow! I'll pick one after some more review... most of the commentary here adds something of value!

Comment: For future reference, problem statements should go beyond "it fails to work"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit... that's fair. Will do next time!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you do `s = *(&s + 1)` the variable `s` is a local variable in an implicit scope that only contains the loop. When you do `&s` you get the address of that local variable, which is unrelated to any of the arrays.

The difference from the previous loop is that there `s` is a pointer to the first element in the array.

---

To explain it a little more "graphically" what you have in the last loop is something like

```
+----+      +---+      +------------+
| &s | ---> | s | ---> | family2[0] |
+----+      +---+      +------------+
```

That is, `&s` is pointing to `s`, and `s` is pointing to `family2[0]`.

When you do `&s + 1` you effectively have something like

```
+------------+
| family2[0] |
+------------+
^
|
+---+----
| s | ...
+---+----
^   ^
|   |
&s  &s + 1
```

Comment: I will agree that `s` is only accessible locally within the loop.  However, shouldn't `&s` be, effectively, a `(char**)` pointing to the first element of `family2`, which itself is a `(char*)`?

Comment: @lifecrisis No, `&s` is a pointer pointing to `s`, nothing else.

Comment: I wonder why this perfectly correct answer has been downvoted.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Obscene if you ask me.

Comment: Hey @Someprogrammerdude, check out the summary edit above, I believe I clearly summarized what came of this discussion. Let me know if there is a problem with it (a more experienced eye would be a big help!).

Answer (score 10):

Pictures help a lot:

```
            +----------+
            | "father" |                                    
            +----------+         +----------+      +-------+      NULL 
   /-----------→1000            | "mother" |      | "son" |        ↑
+-----+           ↑              +----------+      +-------+        |
|  s  | ?         |                  2000            2500           |
+-----+           |                   ↑                ↑            |
 6000  6008 +----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
            |   family2[0]   |   family2[1]   |  family2[2]  |  family2[3]  |
            +----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
                  5000              5008            5016           5024

                    (    &s refers to 6000    ) 
                    ( &s+1 refers to 6008 but )
                    (   *(&s+1) invokes UB    )
```

<sup>Addresses chosen as random integers for simplicity</sup>

---

The thing here is that, although both `s` and `family2[0]` point to the same base address of the string literal `"father"`, the pointers aren't related with each other and has its own different memory location where they are stored. `*(&s+1) != family2[1]`.

You hit UB when you do `*(&s + 1)` because `&s + 1` is a memory location you're not supposed to tamper with, i.e, it doesn't belong to any object you created. You never know what's stored in there => Undefined Behavior.

<sup>Thanks [@2501](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501) for pointing out several mistakes!</sup>

Comment: In the last part of your answer do you mean `&s + 1 != family2[1]`?  Both statements are correct, but I'm just wondering which is more important to notice in this context...

Comment: That's true as well but the types are different. `s+1 != family2[1]` is a comparison of two `char*`s while `&s+1 != family2[1]` is a comparison of a `char**` and a `char*` which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It isn't clear which example are you representing here. Regardless, this is wrong. &s+1 doesn't point to anything. It isn't even a valid object.

Comment: It seems this is the third example. In that case, s+1 points to the second character of "father" and not 1007.

Comment: Also family2[0] and s are using misleading arrows. They point to the same address, 1000, but s points to the left of the column instead of the address.

Comment: And family2[3] doesn't point to address 3000, at which is shown to be an object containing the null address, family2[3] quite literally points to a null address.

Comment: That''s a little better. There are still mistakes. &s doesn't have an address of 7000. Is not an object at all, as it is shown, so it doesn't have an address at all. &s+1 having the address 7008 is nonsense. How would adding to the value of an object change it's address !? &s+1 simply points to 6008, and it doesn't have an address.

Comment: @2501 Thanks. Sorry for the late reply, I was busy yesterday. I was totally confused too! Thanks again! Is there any more problems in the answer?

Comment: This looks corrects, expect that &s+1 is a valid pointer, you're just not allowed to dereference it.

Comment: @2501 IIRC, using `&s+1` is illegal and invokes UB, even if you don't dereference it.

Comment: Pointing one past an object is defined behavior.

Comment: @2501 Hmm. I think that holds true only in the case of arrays. Is it true for any object?

Comment: @2501 It seems I was wrong. You're right. Pointing to `&s+1` is indeed valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef char* string;

int main() {
char *family1[4] = { "father", "mother", "son", NULL };
string family2[4] = { "father", "mother", "son", NULL };

/* Loop #1: Using a simple pointer to step through "family1". */
for (char **p = family1; *p != NULL; p++) {
    printf("%s\n", *p);
}
putchar('\n');

/* Loop #2: Using the typedef for clarity and stepping through
* family2. */
for (string *s = family2; *s != NULL; s++) {
    printf("%s\n", *s);
}
putchar('\n');

/* Loop #3: Again, we use the pointer, but with a unique increment
* step in our for loop.  This fails to work.  Why? */
/*for (string s = family2[0]; s != NULL; s = *(&s + 1)) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
*/
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    printf("%d ",family2[j]);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(family2[j]));
}
printf("\n");
int i = 0;
for (string s = family2[i]; i != 3; s = (s + strlen(family2[i]) + 2),i++) {
    printf("%d ",s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

system("pause");
```

}

this is a example revised from your code,if you run it,you will find the change of the address of the point and the family2, then you will understand the relationship of the loop #3.

Comment: `s = (s + strlen(family2[i]) + 2)` moves `s` out of bounds of the string