# valgrind says i have conditional jump or move depends on initialized value(s)

Tags: c, valgrind

I am having an issue where valgrind is saying that i have a conditional jump or the move depends on initialized values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

ListNodePtr convertBSTtoLinkedList(TreeNodePtr root)
{
    ListNodePtr newNode;
    ListNodePtr leftLinkedList;
    ListNodePtr rightLinkedList;
    ListNodePtr head;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    newNode->key = root->key;
    head = newNode;

    if(root->left != NULL)
    {
        leftLinkedList = convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->left); 
        head = leftLinkedList;

        ListNodePtr conductor;
        conductor = leftLinkedList;
        while (conductor->next != NULL)
        {
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }

        conductor->next = newNode;

    }

    if(root->right != NULL)
    {
        rightLinkedList= convertBSTtoLinkedList(root->right); 
        newNode->next = rightLinkedList;
    }

    return head;
    }
```

valgrind the problem is somewhere in the while loop and i am assuming it is because i havent initialized that conductor->next is NULL, but i dont know how to do that since it it checking if it is NULL

Comment: If there's some awful `typedef ListNode * ListNodePtr;` and its like present in your program, [I suggest you get rid of them ASAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: If you follow the suggestions of valgrind to add in "--track-origins=yes" to your command line, it'll tell you where the uninitialised value comes from

Comment: There's an unrelated bug too (what happens if `malloc()` runs out of memory and returns `NULL`?).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
newNode->key = root->key;
head = newNode;
```

You create a new node and set the key, **but you don't set the `next` pointer**.  While the value does get set if there is a right subtree, it will **not** get set if the node is a leaf node.

When your recursive call for the left side returns after processing a leaf node, it then checks the `next` pointer which was never written to.  By reading an uninitialized value, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make sure that you initialize this pointer to `NULL` when you create the node:

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
newNode->key = root->key;
newNode->next = NULL;
head = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do is when you create a node in some place in your code initialize next with a `NULL`. That will most likely close this message of valgrind.

So add this line in your code

`newNode->next = NULL;`

The problem arises because the value that you are checking to be `NULL` is not initialized with `NULL`. As a result this checking is as if it is with some uninitialized value.

The solution I mentioned is just intializing every node with a proper `next` and `key` value.

---

Few points:

Check if the return value of `malloc` whether it failed or succeeded.

> ```
> if ( newNode == NULL)
> {
>    fprintf(stderr,"Error");
>    exit(1);
> }
> ```