# Passing char * into struct

Tags: c, struct

So, I have a struct member char* and I want to initialize it after allocating node memory .However,this method gets me a Seg Fault.
Note. YES, I want a *infoPtr. Excuse any syntax errors, these are not the problem I am trying to solve . ALL I want is to correctly pass a char* string into name.

```
struct Info{
    char *name;
}
typedef struct Info *infoPtr;
int main(void){
    enter("google");
}
void enter(char *name){
    infoPtr* info=(infoPtr)malloc(sizeof(infoPtr));
    info->name=strup(name);
}
```

Comment: For those that missed the earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926255/passing-values-to-char-struct-member

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
typedef struct Info *infoPtr;
```

`infoPtr` is of `struct Info*` type, this

```
infoPtr* info=(infoPtr)malloc(sizeof(infoPtr)); /* info will be of struct Info** type */
```

should be

```
infoPtr info = malloc(sizeof(*infoPtr)); /* typecasting is not required */
```

Side note, its not considered as good practice to `typedef` a pointer, do read [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice)

Also here

```
info->name=strup(name);
```

you wanted to use `strdup()` instead of `strup()` for e.g

```
info->name=strdup(name);
```

Coming to your question *ALL I want is to correctly pass a char string into name ?* Yes the way you passed argument to `enter()` is correct except **typedefing struct pointer**. And passing string literal `google` like

```
enter("google");
```

and defining `enter()` like

```
void enter(char *name){ /* Its correct */
  /* play with name */
}
```

Comment: This is yet another illustration of why you should never `typedef` a pointer.

Comment: Of course, this means that the the code the OP presented never compiled successfully, and so could never have generated a segfault, so who knows whether this is the real issue that tripped them up.

Comment: Don't forget to `free()` each `strdup()`.