# How to display a linked list that is using Dummy Node?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
typedef struct Node *ptrToNode;
typedef ptrToNode List;
typedef ptrToNode Position;
struct Node
{
    int Element;
    Position Next;
};
void InsertFirst(int x,List L)
{
    Position NewNode;
    NewNode=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(NewNode==NULL)
    {
        printf("Out of Space");
    }
    else 
    {
        NewNode->Element=x;
        NewNode->Next=L->Next;
        L->Next=NewNode;

    }
    
}
void display(List S){
    while(S!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",S->Element);
        S=S->Next;
    }
       
}
int main()
{
    List P;
    int ch;
    P=(List)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    InsertFirst(10,P);
    InsertFirst(20,P);
    InsertFirst(30,P);
    display(P);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone what is wrong with this code? After entering the elements in the linked list. In display part it is starting from the last element and throwing garbage values

[I am getting this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq5LJ.png)

Comment: Please provide driver code that actually produces the wrong output. You speak of a dummy node... but the code you have shared doesn't even create a single node.

Comment: I edited the code, can you check again

Answer (score 0):

Since you created a dummy node, you should just skip over it in your `display` function. Before the loop, do:

```
S = S->Next;
```

In your main code, you should not leave `P->Next` uninitialised, as that gives undefined behaviour. So right after allocating memory for `P`, add:

```
P->Next = NULL;
```

BTW, it is [not considered good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781932/is-typedefing-a-pointer-type-considered-bad-practice) to typedef pointers to structs.